# Calculating omega (ω) in a separately excited DC motor

Tags: dc, dc-motor, electric-machine

I'm currently struggling here so perhaps you can help out. I'm given "three basic equations":

`Magnetic flux of the field winding is given by:`

`ϕ = Kf(shunt)If`

`Torque is given by
T = ϕKaIa`

`EMF developed by the armature is given by:
E = ϕKaω`

I'm now expected to extract an equation for E in terms of `Va` and `Ia`. Then rearrange the equations above to express `Ia` in terms of `T` and `ω` in terms of `E`. THEN I'm supposed to write `w` in terms of `T` and `Va` only. Finally I should then eliminate `ϕ` from the omega question to get a crazy equation. Attached is some images to help you guys understand. Any help would be appreciated as I've spent hours attempting these questions (as seen in the image) but I have no idea if they're correct or how to even answer the final question.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The applied field voltage for a separately excited motor is held constant while Va is changed. So you can use If = Vf/Rf to calculate flux. Then use the equation for torque in terms of flux and Ia to calculate Ia in terms of torque and flux. Substitute that for Ia in the equation for omega in terms of Torque and Va. Divide the torque terms in the numerator by the torque in the denominator and the equation for omega will be in the desired form.